# How to run a perl script inside another perl script

Tags: linux, scripting, perl

I have two Perl scripts and want to use one script from another.

The scripts are called `script1.pl` and `script2.pl`.

I want to run the below command inside `script1.pl` :

```
/home/user/script2.pl /var/log/fw_log error >>/tmp/error.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the Perl's built-in 'system' function:

```
system "/home/user/script2.pl /var/log/fw_log error >>/tmp/error.log";
```

Comment: Hi @drg,

Thanks for the reply. I've used below but getting error:

`system "/home/user/script2.pl" "${BASE_DIR}/${i}/fw_log error" >> "${AUDATA}.${i}"; `

But getting error

Comment: The Error is:

`String found where operator expected at ./script1.pl line 23, near ""/home/user/script2.pl" "${BASE_DIR}/${i}/fw_log error""
 (Missing operator before  "${BASE_DIR}/${i}/fw_log error"?)
syntax error at ./script1.pl line 23, near ""/home/user/script2.pl" "${BASE_DIR}/${i}/fw_log error""
Execution of ./script1.pl aborted due to compilation errors. `